# create c# object from json array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I am receiving an error when trying to convert my json array into an object.

I have a Json array with multiple layers like this :

```
    {  
   "error":"0",
   "result":{  
      "activities":{  
         "1":{  
            "activity_id":"15803",
            "activity_id_name":"Ashtanga vinyasa",
            "schedule":{  
               "1":{  
                  "available":"30",
                  "start":"09:00:00"
               }
            }
         },
         "2":{  
            "activity_id":"15804",
            "activity_id_name":"Yin/Yang",
            "schedule":{  
               "1":{  
                  "available":"30",
                  "start":"10:30:00"
               }
            }
         },
         "3":{  
            "activity_id":"15805",
            "activity_id_name":"Stress relief",
            "schedule":{  
               "1":{  
                  "available":"30",
                  "start":"20:00:00"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "json_code":"2"
   },
   "id":null
}
```

From this i created an object that looks like this :

```
namespace LesRooster.Models
{
    public class JsonGroup
    {
        public string Error { get; set; }
        public List<Results> Result { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }

    }

    public class Results
    {
        public Activities YogaActivities { get; set; }
        public int JsonCode { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Activities
    {
        public int ActivityId { get; set; }
        public string ActivityIdName { get; set; }
        public Schedule LesSchedule { get; set; }
    }

    public class Schedule
    {
        public int Available { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    }

}
```

When I try to add the array to the object with the following line :

```
JsonGroup jgroup = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonGroup>(JsonArrayCode);
```

I am receiving the following error :

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LesRooster.Models.Results]' because
>   the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.

Is there any way to resolve this? I would like to keep it as an object since it is easy to pass on in the view in my mvc5 application.

I have tried googling this but all solutions I have found are for single dimension json arrays.

The documentation of the API I request the json array from looks as follows :

```
json_code   integer 
Constant value: 2
activities  hash    
    {
    index : {
        activity_id: integer
        activity_id_name: string
        schedule: hash
        {
            index : {
                available: integer
                start: time
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The error is exactly what it says it is. In your JSON you have a property `result` that contains an *object*, with a property `activities` with a bunch more properties. That is not an array, so how is it supposed to deserialize it to one? You can either deserialize `activities` to a dictionary, or you can write your own converter to handle that property.

Comment: You don't have collections in JSON message but do have in DT object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of your classes does not match the structure of the JSON - this results in an exception. I have made some changes to your classes to reflect the JSON structure.

The main difference is that Activities is not an `Array` but a `Dictionary`.

```
namespace LesRooster.Models
{
    public class JsonGroup
    {
        public string Error { get; set; }
        public Result Result { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }

    }

    public class Result {
        public IDictionary<string, Activities> Activities {get; set;}
        public int JsonCode {get; set;}
    }        

    public class Activities
    {
        [JsonProperty("activity_id")]
        public int ActivityId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("activity_id_name")]
        public string ActivityIdName { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, Schedule> Schedule { get; set; }
    }

    public class Schedule
    {
        public int Available { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Schedule is a collection too

Comment: @Plutonix: Thanx - rather it is a Dictionary as well. I will update my answer. I am just checking if DateTime for Start is the proper type.

Comment: Just think you need to put a  `[JsonProperty("activity_id_name")]` on ActivityIdName property and `[JsonProperty("activity_id")]` on ActivityId property, or use something like this : https://migara.li/2016/01/09/json-net-easy-serialization/

Comment: Thanks a bunch @rboe !! this did the trick, DateTime appears to be working so it should be the right type.

Comment: And your dictionaries could be of type `<int, ...>` (instead of string)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Added this aswell since the values came out blank otherwise and works like a charm

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) ? it's MIT licenced BTW.

Comment: This answer fails to adress the discrepancy between the code and the recieved JSON message.